# How to read this formula aloud: "f(x) = x²"?

Tags: pronunciation, mathematics, reading-aloud

> [f(x) = x<sup>2</sup>](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_%28mathematics%29)

Having heard this read only in Korean, I don’t know how to read it in English. What is the right English reading?

Comment: You can find a pdf-file called *[How to pronounce mathematical formulae in English](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22How+to+pronounce+mathematical+formulae+in+English%22)* in various places on Internet. (I was not sure, which site is most reliable and most probable to last for a long time, so I've linked to a google search instead.)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It would normally be read aloud as:

> *f of x equals x squared*

There are some variations you might hear. For example, sometimes *is* is used in place of *equals*.

If the exponent was 3, you would say *cubed*. Anything higher than three (say, for example, 5) would generally be read aloud as:

> *f of x is x to the fifth (power)*

or perhaps:

> *f of x is x to the power of five*

Comment: You can read x^4 as "x tesseracted". But okay, hardly anyone does. :-)

Comment: Some people say "f at x" instead of "f of x"

Comment: @Max That's usually used for a constant: "If f of x is x squared, then f at 3 is 9."

Comment: "to the power of" is the general form here - it's appropriate for any exponent, including fractions.  The other versions are all short forms for (specific) whole numbers.

Comment: @Brilliand - I agree. Moreover, the words "power of" are sometimes omitted for the sake of brevity, as in: "x to the two-thirds" or "[e to the i pi](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/8f/E-to-the-i-pi2.svg/380px-E-to-the-i-pi2.svg.png)".

Comment: "a power of" is also fairly common, as well as "raised to the <fifth>". The omission of "power of" in the final example, however, as I would argue, is more necessary than it is optional (at least when speaking), because of how cumbersome it would become when spoken (and the meaning it loses when someone tries to parse it in their head! - would you be able to process "e to the power of the product of i and pi" quickly without stopping to think?)

Comment: Powers of 2 and 3 are used so often that they have their own shorthand: "squared" and "cubed", respectively. "f of x" is understood by anyone who has had some exposure to algebra to mean "There is a function named _f_ that takes as an input [argument, parameter] the value _x_."

Answer (score 0):

f(x)=x<sup>2</sup> is simply read as f of x equals x squared. **f** being the function name and **x** being the input and x<sup>2</sup> serves as the output. https://www.mathsisfun.com/sets/function.html